# Is it possible to programmatically/dynamically determine the size of thumbnails with BackLoad and JQuery File Uploader

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic, jquery-file-upload, backload

I'm using BackLoad and JQuery File Uploader to allow users to upload images to a website.

But the thumbnails need to be different sizes for different areas of the site.

For example: When uploading photos into a gallery I want thumbs to be 180x180
But when uploading Mugshots I want thumbs to be a max width of 120.

Anybody know if this can be achieved with Backload? Or am I stuck with the one size?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see in the documentation, there doesn't appear to be support for multiple thumbnail sizes. Personally, I wouldn't rely on BackLoad for creating your thumbnails, anyways. It's really more of a corollary feature for BackLoad, rather than something they really focus on, anyways.

Instead, use something for this that is designed for the purpose, like [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/). That will let you create thumbs on the fly in whatever sizes you like, anytime you like -- much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks Chris you're absolutely right, I've wasted a lot of my time with BackLoad. BackToTheDrawingBoard.